# Wi-Fi option gone in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04

The Wi-Fi option in Ubuntu 20.04 suddenly disappeared for me. The option to select a Wi-Fi network is gone.

I am using TP-Link TL WN823N RTL8192EU. It is shown in the `sudo lsusb` output, but it's not working.

Comment: can you add to your question the output of this commands? `ifconfig` `iwconfig` `systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service`.

Comment: it says "iconfig" not found

Comment: Try `sudo apt update` `sudo apt install net-tools` and then try the commands from the comment above.

Comment: spelling counts.